# Why Reflection Calls Do Not Work Anymore in Java 17?

Tags: java, java-module, java-17

We migrated from Java 8 to Java 17 and the following error started to pop up due to a reflection call in the code:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.twitter.chill.Instantiators$ cannot access a member of class org.apache.avro.Schema$StringSchema with modifiers "public"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:489)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.twitter.chill.Instantiators$.$anonfun$normalJava$1(KryoBase.scala:169)
    at com.twitter.chill.Instantiators$$anon$1.newInstance(KryoBase.scala:137)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

If I understand correctly, the problem is in the new Java modular system and I need to open some modules to make it work. **So how do I know what modules I should open?**

I looked at the error message and thought it required me to add `--add-opens=org.apache/org.apache.avro=com.twitter.chill` to allow the package `com.twitter.chill` to access `org.apache.avro.Schema`, but it does not work. I also tried `--add-opens=org.apache/org.apache.avro=java.base/jdk.internal.reflect` with the same success (or rather its absence).

Comment: Does “migrated from Java 8 to Java 17” imply that you started actively using modules? As otherwise, if you just run the same software the same way you did with Java 8, all classes loaded through the classpath belong to the same module anyway.

Comment: Just changed the JVM version on which we run the code from 8 to 17 and started to get the errors related to the modular system. Nothing else changed in relation to how we run the code

Comment: @Holger When you place a JAR on the module path, the JAR is treated as a module.

Comment: But *did* you place the jars on the module path? That would be a significant change in the way you run the code.

Comment: Nope, I did not. So I suppose it would place all the jars as "Unnamed" and still require separate permission for access like `--add-opens=org.apache/org.apache.avro=ALL-UNNAMED`?

Comment: If all the jars are still on the class path, they are all put into the _same_ unnamed module. And code within the same module can still access each other. I think the error you are seeing is not related to module encapsulation. In those cases, the error message should be more elaborate and explain which module boundary blocked the access.

Comment: @JornVernee I see, it makes sense. What I do not understand then: is why the code works on Java 8 but throws `IllegalAccessException` on Java 17 if not for the stricter encapsulation rules.

Comment: @ClassNotFoundException I'm not sure either, but it might be related to: https://openjdk.org/jeps/181 which changes how the compiler and VM treat accesses to nested classes.

Comment: I suggest trying to create a small program that reproduces the issue first, and then perhaps asking another question based on the program.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the link, @JornVernee I will investigate further

Comment: JEP 181 would only make a difference if the source code was recompiled with the new Java version and if the constructor was `private` but it is reported to be `public` (which is a bit strange considering that the class itself is not `public`). The exception type and message is exactly the same with 8 and 17 when `setAccessible(true)` has not been called and the access is granted in each version when it has.

Comment: The error message is confusing. It refers to the access modifier of the outer class while trying to instantiate a private inner class. And it does so without using `setAccessible` which is the main problem, as you rightfully pointed it out @Holger. So there is indeed no problem with the modules access. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: No, I did my own tests and the exception correctly reports the member’s modifiers. Thinking about it, this scenario is not so strange, as e.g. my IDE also likes to generate methods and constructors with `public` modifier even if the declaring class is not `public`, so I have to remove them by hand. So if someone used a similar tool and did not fix them manually, they may end up with a `public` constructor at a non-`public` inner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real issue is that `org.apache.avro.Schema$StringSchema` is a [private inner class](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/42822886c28ea74a744abb7e7a80a942c540faa5/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.java#L1290), so you don't have access to its members (public or otherwise) from outside its declaring class

Comment: That is indeed private, but it should be possible to access it with deep reflection, shouldn't it? So my question would be then: how do I make a `private static class` accessible for deep reflection in Java 17? As I mentioned, I tried `--add-opens=org.apache/org.apache.avro=com.twitter.chill` but without success. Perhaps I am specifying the wrong modules? But then: how do I know what modules do I need to open?

Comment: Or does Java 17 completely forbids deep reflection?

Comment: You don't do deep reflection - you never call `Constructor.setAccessible(true)`. Without deep reflection, the constructor checks if both the class is public (if the class is in a different package) and that the constructor is public (if the declaring class is in a different nest). No amount of `--add-opens` or `--add-exports` will change that.

Comment: @ClassNotFoundException you're going to need to call `Constructor.setAccessible(true)` as mentioned above before creating instances. Not sure why it is not needed with Java8. As for the `add-opens` I don't think there's such thing as `org.apache` module. If you just put all your jars on classpath, they all become parts of a single 'Unnamed' module, so you are not crossing any module boundaries here. BTW correct syntax for `add-opens` is `module/package=module` rather than `module/package=package`, meaning "make that package accessible from another module"

Comment: @peterz You were right, the problem has to do with the stricter encapsulation rules in Java 17.

Comment: @peterz actually, it is needed for Java 8 as well. It’s not clear why the problem does not occur with Java 8 for the OP. Maybe, the software does not even try this access, because it does something else in this version.